# Ansible - Get Facts from Remote Windows Hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am using Ansible / Ansible Tower and would like to determine what facts are available on my Windows host. The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) states that I can run the following:

```
ansible hostname -m setup
```

How would I incorporate this into a playbook I run from Ansible Tower so I can gather the information from hosts?

Here is the current playbook per the assistance given:

```yaml
# This play outputs the facts of the Windows targets in scope

- name: Gather Windows Facts 
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

  - setup:
    register: ansible_facts

  - debug: item
    with_dict: ansible_facts
```

However, running this produces the following error:

```yaml
ERROR! this task 'debug' has extra params, which is only allowed in
the following modules: command, shell, script, include, include_vars,
add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `gather_facts` which is true by default. It is equivalent to running `setup` module.

```
- hosts: ....
  gather_facts: yes
```

The facts are saved in ansible variables to be used in playbooks. See [System Facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts)

There are many ways to display the ansible facts. For you to understand how it works, try the following:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - setup:
    register: ansible_facts
  - debug: item
    with_dict: ansible_facts
```

Comment: Where does the output display / how do I get this to output?

Comment: Is there a way to output the large list so I know what the variables are? In their example, it provides a large Ubuntu ouput. With these listed, I can know now what I can use as variables. Here is lists a fact_path but unsure how this works in a playbook http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html

Comment: Received an error (newer to Playbooks) on -debug: The offending line appears to be:

    register: ansible_facts
  - debug: item
    ^ here

Comment: Post your playbook or try the one I posted.

Comment: Done, I have a gather_facts: yes while you have true

Answer (score 0):

Testing and working through it, this is working for me:

```
- name: Gather Windows Facts 
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=vars
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```