# How to reference an environment variable in an Ansible task?

Tags: ansible

Why can't I reference an environment variable **inside a command?**

Consider this playbook:

```yaml
- name: Test env variables
  hosts: my-host
  vars:
    archive_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'ARCHIVE_NAME') }}"
    
    - name: Clone Git repository
      ansible.builtin.git:
        repo: git@github.com:myproject/myrepo.git
        dest: sources
        archive: "{{ archive_name }}" # <- This works
        #archive: "{{ ansible_env.ARCHIVE_NAME }}" # <- this does not work
```

Same problem when used in another command:

```yaml
- name: Copy artifact to build server
  command: scp sources/{{ ansible_env.ARCHIVE_NAME }} root@{{ groups['my-host-5'][0] }}:/root/sources/{{ ansible_env.ARCHIVE_NAME }}
```

Is this a syntax or formatting issue?

Comment: `"{{ lookup('env', 'ARCHIVE_NAME') }}"` is running on the Control Node, whereby your task is running on the Remote Node with facts from the Remote Node. Therefore both values might be different. Just gather facts instead and debug the values. See under [How to lookup `env` on Managed Node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325914/6771046).

Comment: You are right. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it ✅

Comment: since it seems to be  a duplicate for me, you could just upvote the other given answer.